# How can I find and delete a certain node from a linked list. java using these specific classes

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to do a project and I'm not sure how to find and delete a certain node in a linked list. my professor wants us to use these exact classes.

```
public class StudentList {

    private StudentNode shead ;

    public StudentList(){}
    public void setShead(StudentNode sh)
    {
        shead = sh;
    }

    public StudentNode getShead()
    {
        return shead;
    }
    public void deleteStudentNode(StudentNode s)
    {      
    }

    public StudentNode findStudentByName(String s)
    {
    }
}
```

I won't waste space for the Accessor and Mutator methods for the next classes

student class

```
public class Student extends Person{

    private String major;
    private double gpa;
    public Student(){}
}
```

person class

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    public Person(){}
    public Person (String n, String g)
    {
        n = name;
        g = gender;
    }
}
```

EDIT -here is the student node

```
public class StudentNode {
private Student student;
private StudentNode sptr;
private FriendList fptr;

StudentNode()
{ }

public StudentNode(Student s)
{
    s = student;
}       

public void setStudent(Student s)
{
    student = s;
}

public Student getStudent()
 {
    return(student);
}

public void setSptr(StudentNode s)
{
    sptr = s;
} 

public StudentNode getSptr()
{
    return(sptr);
}
```

Comment: So you have to create the `StudentNode` class yourself? Have you done any work on that? (and show us!)

Comment: @StephenP i added it now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find or delete a student node with student name, you need to access the name field. You can add some getter/setter for Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String n, String g) {
        n = name;
        g = gender;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then implement the find and delete like this:

```
public class StudentList {

    private StudentNode shead;

    public StudentList() {
    }

    public void setShead(StudentNode sh) {
        shead = sh;
    }

    public StudentNode getShead() {
        return shead;
    }


    private boolean isSameStudent(Student a, Student b) {
        return a != null && b != null && a.getName().equals(b.getName());
    }

    public void deleteStudentNode(StudentNode s) {
        if (s == null) {
            // Cannot delete a null node
            return;
        }
        if (isSameStudent(s.getStudent(), shead.getStudent())) {
            // If the node to delete is head
            shead = shead.getSptr();
            return;
        }
        StudentNode ptr = shead;

        while (ptr != null) {
            if (ptr.getSptr() == null) {
                // There is no node after ptr
                return;
            }
            if (isSameStudent(ptr.getSptr().getStudent(), s.getStudent())) {
                // The next node is the node to delete
                ptr.setSptr(ptr.getSptr().getSptr());
                break;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getSptr();
        }
    }

    public StudentNode findStudentByName(String s) {
        StudentNode ptr = getShead();
        while (ptr != null) {
            if (ptr.getStudent().getName().equals(s)) {
                return ptr;
            }
            ptr = ptr.getSptr();
        }
        // not found
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hop it could help you!